# Efficient way to select and copy down to the last row of data

Tags: vba, excel

**Context**
I've built a model in Excel which allows users to load budgets and pay data from a download from a pay system. The users can load a cost centres budget (in the I_Budget sheet) adjust it, press save and the data is dumped into a 'SavedData' sheet. Whereby they can then load another cost centre into I_Budget.

However if the user makes a mistake or wishes to revise their previously edited budgets in SavedData they can click 'Load' in I_Budget and the data will be copied across.

**VBA Code**
The code to load the users budgets from SavedData:

```
Public Sub LoadUsersSavedBudgets()

    Const WORKSHEET_DATA = "SavedData"
    Const WORKSHEET_BUDGET = "I_Budget"
    Const START_CELL = "A2"
    Const END_COLUMN = "H"

    ' Check if the user can perform the load action
    If IsEmpty(Sheets(WORKSHEET_DATA).Range("A2").Value) Then Exit Sub

    Worksheets(WORKSHEET_BUDGET).Unprotect

    ' A fudge to make Excel copy the data in the sheet
    Worksheets(WORKSHEET_DATA).Visible = True

    ' Select all rows in the selection
    Call DynamicColumnSelector(WORKSHEET_DATA, START_CELL, END_COLUMN)

    ' Set the range of the selected cells
    Set Rng = Application.Selection

    ' Copy the selection
    Rng.Copy

    ' Now paste the results
    With Sheets(WORKSHEET_BUDGET).Range("A18")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    Worksheets(WORKSHEET_BUDGET).Protect

    ' Clear the data in I_Budget to give the user a blank canvas
    Call DeleteUsersSavedBudgets

    Worksheets(WORKSHEET_DATA).Visible = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Sheets(WORKSHEET_BUDGET).Select

    MsgBox "Success! Your budgets have been loaded."

End Sub
```

The code to save the users budgets into SavedData:

```
Public Sub SaveUsersBudgetAdjustments()

    Const WORKSHEET_BUDGET = "I_Budget"
    Const START_CELL = "A18"
    Const END_COLUMN = "H"
    Const WORKSHEET_OUTPUT = "SavedData"
    Const FILTER_COST_CENTRE = "I_Setup!I16"

    Dim nRng As Range

    ' Protect user from running this method if no data has been laoded
    If IsEmpty(Range("I_Budget!H18").Value) = True Then Exit Sub

    ' Issue warning to user
    If MsgBox("Would you like so save your changes into the O_Budget sheet?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "You can always load them again for editing.", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' We make sure the budget adjustments have been taken into account before any saving begins
    Call UpdateRevisedBudget

    Worksheets(WORKSHEET_BUDGET).Unprotect

    ' Select all rows in the selection
    Call DynamicColumnSelector(WORKSHEET_BUDGET, START_CELL, END_COLUMN)

    ' Set the range of the selected cells
    Set Rng = Application.Selection

    ' Delete the destination contents
    'Sheets(WORKSHEET_OUTPUT).Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Clear

    ' Copy and paste the selection into the destination sheet
    Rng.Copy

    ' A fudge to allow the copying and pasting of data to work
    If IsEmpty(Sheets(WORKSHEET_OUTPUT).Range("A2").Value) Then
            With Sheets(WORKSHEET_OUTPUT).Range("A2")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
    Else
            With Sheets(WORKSHEET_OUTPUT).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Rows.Offset(1, 0)
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
    End If

    ' and clear the selection contents
    Selection.ClearContents

    Worksheets(WORKSHEET_BUDGET).Protect

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Perhaps of most interest is the method I call to dynamically select data down to the last row:

```
Private Sub DynamicColumnSelector(shtValue, StartCellValue, StartColumnValue)

    'Best used when column length is static
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim StartCell As Range

    Set sht = Worksheets(shtValue)
    Set StartCell = Range(StartCellValue)

    'Refresh UsedRange
    Worksheets(shtValue).UsedRange

    'Find Last Row
    LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    'Select Range
    Sheets(shtValue).Select
    sht.Range(StartCellValue & ":" & StartColumnValue & LastRow).Select

End Sub
```

**The Exam Question**
My question is that whilst the above works, it feels smelly and inefficient. Is there a better way I can select data in the sheets and copy it across? I have to take into account the last row within the SavedData sheet as we may be continually adding data to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding the last row number should work this way (which is not really shorter, only a little bit simpler):

```
    sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

In your case, this should yield the same result as `sht.Cells.Find`, since you accessed `UsedRange` before. However, the `Find` operation should deliver the last nonempty row even if you do not access `UsedRange` before, where the `SpecialCells`solution might return a row number which is actually bigger, because the user filled some values there, deleted the values and did not save the document before.

Moreover, I would avoid to call a sub which selects a range which is then grabbed by the next function by `Application.Selection`. Better, make `DynamicColumnSelector` a function returning the `Range` in stake:

```
 Function DynamicColumnSelector(...) as Range
 ' ...
     Set DynamicColumnSelector=sht.Range(...)
 End Function
```

and call it like this

```
 Set Rng = DynamicColumnSelector(...)
 Rng.Copy
```

This makes your code much more robust against later changes. Code which changes or relies on the global selection is error prone when you have to change the order of execution later, or insert some additional code in between. Worse, it is longer, slower and has visual effects to the user.  Code which passes the range objects directly does not have these problems.

Unfortunately, the `PasteSpecial` operations are only available in conjunction with the clipboard, not directly for a range-to-range copy. If you going to copy just values, you do not need `PasteSpecial`, but if you want to copy formats as wll, this is probably the easiest and most secure solution. So I would not expect that there is a much simpler solution for copy/pasting than the one you found by yourself.

As you asked: copying just values without any formats, without the clipboard:

```
Set rng = DynamicColumnSelector(...)
Set destinationRng = Sheets(WORKSHEET_OUTPUT).Range("A2")
rng.Copy destinationRng
```

does it.

Comment: +1 for simplicity however it doesn't answer my question about making the copy and paste of a selection more efficient

Comment: Thanks Doc. So formatting aside (I believe conditional formatting will suffice), in line with my question, how do I do a neat 'paste' to another sheet without doing a paste special?